# Nginx Gzip not working with EB

Tags: nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

[image][image][image]Gzip not working.
I am getting response header as gzip but the response is not zipped.
I verified it in https://checkgzipcompression.com/ as well.
 Its sitting in front of golang app but I dont think it will affect this in any case.

```
# Elastic Beanstalk Nginx Configuration File

user                    nginx;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes        auto;[enter image description here][1]
worker_rlimit_nofile    133979;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    include       conf.d/*.conf;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default     "upgrade";
    }       

    server {  
        listen        80 default_server;
        access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log main;             

        client_header_timeout 60;
        client_body_timeout   60;
        keepalive_timeout     60;

        gzip on;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_min_length 10240;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
        gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

        # Include the Elastic Beanstalk generated locations
        include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;
    }
}
```

Comment: The response header `Content-Encoding` states that it is `gzip`?

Comment: I dont know why is it showing like this in Chrome and CheckGzipCompression.com. I checked the result in Mozilla and result came as expected. Hence, I did performance testing through jmeter and results looks satisfactory.

Comment: @Shawn C.  Yup that was the first line of my post.